# automapper with generics in N-Layer project

Tags: c#, generics, automapper

I have a project structure as below

**App.Model** - contains entity models

**App.Repo** - Contains generic repository

**App.Domain** - Contains Business objects

**App.Services** - contains Services

My repository returns Entity model and I want to convert it to a business model and return it to the service layer.

If it is non-generic I could use

```
Mapper.Map<MyDomainModel>(MyEntityModel);
```

But how to do with generics?
My generic repository code is as below

```
public class Repository<TEntity,TDomain> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{

    public TDomain GetById(int id)
    {
        //Instad of below line I want to convert it to DomainModel and return it
        //return _db.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
    }

}
```

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Open-Generics.html

Comment: @aaron thanks for the link. Will give a try :)